# Fixing/restoring HDD boot data (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, amazon-web-services

I increased the size of a partition (After modifying the size of an `EBS Volume`)

Prior to resizing I got the following warning:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************
```

Converting to GPT seemed to do a little damage.

The partition resize seems to be successful, I can mount and access files.

Post resize, I can no longer boot the machine using that EBS volume, the volumes does not seem to be a boot volume.

The machine hangs on boot:

[image]

Here's the disk info, let me know if you need to see anything else

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   50G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   50G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  120G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0  120G  0 part
$ sudo gdisk /dev/xvdf
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/xvdf: 251658240 sectors, 120.0 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): EDA0C666-2A70-4C8A-A1A8-77908890A1A8
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 251658206
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048       251658206   120.0 GiB   EF00  EFI System
```

How can I restore the boot functionality to that disk?

Answer (score 0):

Didnt find a solution to the broken mbr/gpt boot data.

Instead I re-did the resize process with `parted` instead of `gdisk` (using a snapshot backup).